# How do I get my laptop's screen brightness settings back?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-management, display, brightness

From when I bought it up until yesterday, my laptop would dim the screen automatically if you let it sit for long enough, and then if you hit a key or moved the mouse, the brightness would jump back to what you had it at.  I enjoy that behavior.  It works well.

Then I booted it up today, and found that now it will dim the screen automatically if you let it sit for long enough, but it doesn't restore the screen brightness.  I have to do that manually, every single time, and it's getting really old really fast.

It's an Alienware M17 running Windows 7 64-bit, in case that helps.

EDIT: After a bit of testing, I've found out that it only does this on the Power Saver profile, while on AC power.  Other power profiles work fine, as does Power Saver on the battery.  But I can't find anything in the control panel that looks like it would affect this.

Answer (score 1):

In the tray, rightclick the battery and choose power options.

Choose your active plan by clicking the "Change plan settings" and then either adjust the slides there or click "Change advance power settings".

The third choice from the bottom will give you additional options when it comes to setting the screen brightness.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, there are lots of interesting options in there, including settings for dimming the display, but nothing about getting it back when you hit a key, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you access the *FX* in the Alienware *Command Center* and try  to modify the settings related to the *Display* (you might need to access the Advanced Settings here, I am not sure, as I don't have the laptop with me and I'm still new with Alienware :) 
I even suggest writing down the settings you find initially so you can bring them back in case you don't like the end-result or to know how you modified them and what happened.

It is no hardware issue, but just the settings. You might have modified them without knowing or perhaps they have been modified while installing or updating something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered, that this might be a hardware/bios setting? I know, that e.g. on a Dell (which is basically the same company as alienware right now), you could influence the described diming via BIOS settings and also toggle a related automatic brightness mode with -. What I am saying is, that the whole problem might not be windows related.